# Java для продолжающих: что почитать?

Tags: java, книги

Есть много хороших книг по Java: Thinking in Java, Effective Java, Java Concurrency in Practice etc.

Хотелось бы почитать что-то более углубленное. Что бы вы могли посоветовать? Для себя набросал ряд тем которые мне кажутся интересными:

- 1) внутренности JVM: устройство,
     производительность, GC
- 2) устройство серверов
     приложений/сервлет контейнеров. как
     обрабатываются запросы, как создаются
     сервлеты, итд. что-то типа Apache
     Tomcat изнутри, к примеру.
- 3) classloaders
- 4) какие-то полезные для java
     web-разработки книги - может
     протоколы вглубь, может сокеты итп

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Отличный набор книг, которые не только нужно прочитать, но и здорово было бы иметь под рукой.

1. Joshua Bloch "Effective Java"
2. James Gosling, Bill Joy, Guy Steele, Gilad Bracha "The Java Language Specification"
3. Brian Goetz, Tim Peierls, Joshua Bloch, Joseph Bowbeer, David Holmes, Doug Lea "Java Concurrency in Practice"
4. Doug Lea "Concurrent Programming in Java: Design Principles and Pattern"
5. Charlie Hunt, Binu John "Java Performance"

Кроме этого, есть множество книг, посвященных какой-то конкретной теме (generics, IO, NIO и т.д. и т.п.).

Книги также ссылаются на другие источники, которые наверняка будут полезны.

Но не java единой. В смысле web-разработки неплохо бы более глубоко изучить HTTP. В смысле разработки распределенных и высоконагруженных систем, полезным становится знание особенностей работы сети. В смысле работы с данными - реляционные и NoSQL БД.

Можно продолжать очень долго. Лучше исходить из конкретных задач, т.к. полученные знания можно будет закрепить на практике.

И конечно не стоит забывать о блогах по интересующей тематике.

Comment: Спасибо, а Java Performance - слышал там в основном про инструменты Oracle, завлекалово такое, или действительно фундаментальная книга?

Answer (score 5):

Никогда точно не помешает ознакомиться с нюансами производительности в ["Блох Дж. - Java. Эффективное программирование (Java из первых рук) - 2002"](http://www.ozon.ru/context/detail/id/1259354/). По сервлетам очень хороша ["Брюс У. Перри. Java сервлеты и JSP. Сборник рецептов"](http://www.ozon.ru/context/detail/id/4434287/). И тоже никогда не помешает хотя бы ознакомиться с шаблонами в ["Стивен Стелтинг - Применение шаблонов Java"](http://www.ozon.ru/context/detail/id/1221078/) особенно если есть мысли сдавать экзамен по квалификации сеньёра.

Comment: Первое издание Effective Java устарело. Лучше сразу читать второе.

Comment: Спасибо, а Стелтинг лучше той известной книги GoF Patterns?

Comment: В GoF Pattertns на плюсах примеры приводятся, и книга несет скорее общий характер. А у Стенлинга в основном описываются шаблоны характерные для Java. Плюс в GoF есть такие шаблоны, которых точно не будет у Стенлинга ввиду различий языков (C++ vs. Java).

Comment: А я думал что GOF Patterns это по Джаве... ясно, спасибо!